# List initialization approach

Tags: java, collections

What is the difference between these two initialization of List :

```
List<Integer> aa = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> aaa = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: thats called polymorphism my friend, a topic which is covered in every java textbook!

Answer (score 0):

## Polymorphism

The first uses [polymorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) to assign an object to a reference variable whose type is the [interface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)) [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). This is preferable.

In OOP, it is a good practice to assign objects to variables of the most general superclass or interface. If the calling code needs only the methods defined as part of `List`, and not the additional methods defined in `ArrayList`, then go with `List`.

This gives your code the freedom to switch to a different implementation of `List`, some class other than `ArrayList`, without breaking any calling code.

This is a basic Java 101 concept that should be mastered sooner rather than later on your Java education.